# apply an optimal function to a function using a for loop in r

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I wrote a simple function for maximum likelihood and would like this function to give different result based on the different values of its parameters using `for` loop in R. That is my function include an expression based on `for` loop.  My function works well and the result are saved in a list. Then, Since I have two different results, I would like to apply the `optim` function to my function based on each part of my function. For example,

```
ff <- function(x,mu=c(2,0.5),sd=c(0.2,0.3)){
  out <- vector("list",2)
  for (i in 1:2){
    out[[i]] <- -sum(log(dnorm(x,mu[[i]],sd[[i]]))) ## here I have two different part of my funcitons wrap as one using for loop.
  }
return(out)
}


 set.seed(123)
    x <- rnorm(10,2,0.5)
    x
```

Then the result of my function is:

```
> ff(x)
[[1]]
[1] 25.33975

[[2]]
[1] 101.4637
```

Then, since my function has two different parts wrap as one using `for` loop, I would like to apply the optim function to this function based on each part of it. I tried many own methods and they did not work. Here is one of my tries:

```
op <- vector("list",2)
for(i in 1:2){

op <- optim(c(0.5,0.5),fn=ff[[i]],i=i)
}
```

That is, I want the `optim` function to evaluate my function at the first value of my argument `i=1` and then evaluate the function for the second one `i=2`.

So my funcitons without the wrap is as follows:

```
ff_1 <- function(x,mu=c(2,0.5),sd=c(0.2,0.3)){
      -sum(log(dnorm(x,mu[[1]],sd[[1]]))) 

    return(out)
    }

 ff_2 <- function(x,mu=c(2,0.5),sd=c(0.2,0.3)){
      -sum(log(dnorm(x,mu[[2]],sd[[2]]))) 

    return(out)
    }
```

and I then need to use two different `optim` functions for each functions.

I search many website and R help sites but I couldnot find a solution to this question.

Any help please?

Comment: I think my problem is how to make the `optim` function to automatically move over the `i` of my funciton.

Comment: can you please use `set.seed()` so your outputs can be reproduced?

Comment: Thank @mtoto for your comment, I did.

Comment: There is an error in your code. Change: L <- vector("list",2) with: op <- vector("list",2)

Comment: Yes @Sandri you are correct, thank you. But it still does not work.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that you wanted to evaluate (1) `mu = 2 and sd = 0.3` then (2) `mu = 0.5 and sd = 0.3`?

Comment: Yes and that must be done by repeat the functions two times. That because optim as I understand only accept one function at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, it's just the way of passing the arguments to optim, I suppose

```
# given data
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10,2,0.5)

# use vector parOpt instead of specifying two; for convience
# with optim
ff <- function(x, parOpt){
  out  <- -sum(log(dnorm(x, parOpt[1], parOpt[2]))) 
  return(out)
}


# parameters in mu,sd vectors arranged in list
params <- list(set1 = c(2, 0.2), set2 = c(0.5, 0.3))

# output list
out <- list()

for(i in 1:2){
  # pass params (mu and sd) to optim, function ff and the data
  # note, since function ff has x argument, specify that in optim
  out[[i]] <- optim(par = params[[i]], fn=ff ,x=x)

}
```

Should give something like this:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$par
[1] 2.0372546 0.4523918

[[1]]$value
[1] 6.257931

[[1]]$counts
function gradient 
      55       NA 

[[1]]$convergence
[1] 0

[[1]]$message
NULL


[[2]]
[[2]]$par
[1] 2.037165 0.452433

[[2]]$value
[1] 6.257932

[[2]]$counts
function gradient 
      73       NA 

[[2]]$convergence
[1] 0

[[2]]$message
NULL
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your are amaizing @din. That is what I was looking forwoard. Five starts from me to your answer.

Comment: may we can keep the first function and set the parameters as this: `ff <- function(x,params  list(set1 = c(2, 0.2), set2 = c(0.5, 0.3))){ff <- function(x, parOpt){
  out  <- -sum(log(dnorm(x, parOpt[1], parOpt[2]))) 
  return(out)
}}`. What do you think @din.

Comment: I actually can't imagine how the optim will work with a loop inside the function doing the same the thing.

Comment: The idea is to build you function and then apply optim to it. if we have two loops inside the basic function, then I think it is ok.

Comment: Not sure. Why not give it a go and see what happens. But to me, try to think of what you wanted to do and evaluate which solution will be best to you =D

Comment: sorry @din for any inconvence today. Could you please edit your answer at `for (i in i:2)` to be `for (i in 1:2)`. Also, I think we can add some name for the output for any conveinet especially for complex one. `out <- list(out1=out[[1]],out2=out[[2]])`. Thank you so much again.

Comment: I tried your function and it is work very well. I will modify it and see which one is better. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can find the same solution using the command `fitdist` of the `fitdistrplus` package:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10,2,0.5)
mu.start <- c(2,0.5)
sd.start <- c(0.2,0.3)
op <- vector("list",2)
for(i in 1:2){
  op[[i]] <- fitdist(x,"norm", start=c(mu.start[i],sd.start[i]))
}
op
```

The result is:

```
[[1]]
Fitting of the distribution ' norm ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
   estimate Std. Error
1 2.0372546  0.1430588
2 0.4523918  0.1011464

[[2]]
Fitting of the distribution ' norm ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
  estimate Std. Error
1 2.037165  0.1430719
2 0.452433  0.1011694
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Does, the `fitdist` only work for maximum likelihood.

Comment: it seems it is easier than `optim` in use, however, optim can work with other mehtods such as Expectation Maximization Algorithm.